# equivalent of application.doevents() in a web app?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

What is the best practice to emulate what Application.DoEvents() does in a windows standalone application?

I have a vb.net web app, and there is a page with a button that does the following:

(button click)

Sub (button click)

hide asp.panel that contains the button that was just clicked
      insert a record into db
      EmailPeople()

End Sub

Sub EmailPeople()
      send email to 1 or more people
End Sub

---

When clicked, there is a 5-6 second pause while the email sub does it's thing, then after that the panel disappears.  I would prefer that the panel disappears instantly so users don't continue to button mash and insert extra records into the db.....

Advice?

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't it be more practical to spawn the routine off into a separate thread?

Comment: My advice: Don't do that. Don't do a postback. Just create a webmethod, which you call via AJAX. You can assume that it will succeed and hide the panel. You can handle the actual result with a Javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

**Application.DoEvents was evil**, and there was never a reason to use it. And there will never be a reason to use it.

You can make an own thread (async function), (as Chris Fannin said), you can move the logic into a webservice and make an ajax request.

Also .Net 4.5 have a Method called SendMailAsync (System.Net.Mail)

May this sample can help you get in the right direction:
[Send Mail with Background Thread](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-send-email-Asynchronously-in-ASPNet-using-Background-Thread.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes in a web app you might have a background job with a "busy loop" (a term from game dev) that does some heavy calculation and you might worry that it will lock the CPU at 100% blocking everything else from running on that machine

If that's the case - use `Thread.Yield` inside the long-running loop

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.yield?view=netcore-3.1